What exactly is specific gravity and how is it related to fluid statics?
The question is

A cubical block of wood of edge 3cm floats in water. The lower surface of the cube just touches the free end of a vertical spring fixed at the bottom of the pot. Find the maximum weight that can be put on the block without wetting it. Density of wood: 800 km/m³ and spring constant: 50 N/m. Take g: 10m/s²


What does it mean when it's floating? That only the bottom is in contact with the water?
What does it mean to not wet the block? It's already wet, right?
The solution says to find specific gravity. What is it and how does it help us in this problem and just generally in fluid statics?

The solution given in the book is

Why they are finding the specific gravity and then using it to find the height of the part that is submerged in the water?

It would helpful if you tried to read the theory of the book you are reading (HC Verma, that is), all your doubts would have been answered if you did so but nonetheless,
i) Floating could really mean anything, it could mean anything from only little of it is submerged to only a part of it is submerged (and everything in between ofc).
ii) Not wetting the block means that there are no adhesive forces here, that is to say no water molecules are latched onto the surface of the cube. If you were to pull the block up you would find that it is completely dry. That is what it means in general, however here they mean to say that if you were to put a weight on the block, how much would it have to be so that the whole block below it is just submerged and no water touches the weight you have added onto the block.
iii) Specific Gravity is simply another way of expressing the density of the substance. $$  \text{Specific Gravity} = \dfrac {\rho_\text{substance}}{\rho_\text{water}} $$
Where $\rho$ is density.
What exactly did you not understand in the solution? They have just balanced forces along the vertical direction. I strongly recommend you to read the theory of the chapter before solving it.

I did read the theory before attempting the examples but I have to admit I am still not strong in this lesson... and the part I didn't understand from the solution is why and how they are using specific gravity to find the part that is submerged and the part that is not... I tried to find something related to specific gravity from the chapter and found none so that's why I asked the question in this platform... But I do understand the parts (balancing the forces and stuff) in the solution

I have made a few corrections to my answer, I misread the question before, I'm sorry. The reason is Archimedes principle try balancing the forces before you added the weight you would find out that it is in proportion to the density. If the spring's natural length were to be till the surface of water then the height would have been different but here in this question the spring's natural length is till the base of the block of wood so before the weight is added on the block of wood only gravity and buoyant forces are acting on the block.
